# Transpose multiple rows into one column

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

```
ID           Description
1              name1
2              name2
3              name3
4              name4
```

I would like to have the following

```
ID+name
 1
 name1
 2
 name2
 3
 name3
 4
 name4
```

Do you advise something in particular?
Already tried some other transpose methods but I am not able to manage two rows in a time.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you can provide what you have tried so far, it would be easier to provide an answer. Initial thought: capture your data in an array and then transpose it

Comment: It could be done with Macros.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any builtin feature for this type of transpose.

Comment: Congrats! You have just achieved some of the Excel limits! In order to go beyond them, you have to **unlock** VBA. Read more here - https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices#t=2017080208475764339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use formula then following might be helpful.

Enter following formula in `Cell D2`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$B$5,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS($A$2:$B$5)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS($A$2:$B$5),COLUMNS($A$2:$B$5))+1)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

### For @Vityata :

With data in `G17:H20` and formula in `I10`

[image]

With data in `G18:H21` and formula in `I12`

[image]

Comment: Really much appreciated! Thank you very much for your help! It works wonderful!

Comment: @Mrig - I don't won't to be the bringer of the bad news, but this will only work when you are lucky - e.g. if you put the range in `G17:H20` and the formulas somewhere in `R13`, then the whole solution gives an error.

Comment: @Vityata - First formula in my answer is generic and can be used anywhere in the sheet just by changing the range. And what you are saying stands true for the second formula.

Comment: @Vityata - Well I guess its better to remove second formula.

Comment: @Mrig - I am really not sure that even the first formula would work. Try it in Range `G17:H20` with writing the formula in `I10`. Then try it in range `G18:H22` in writing in `I12`. At least one of these two scenarios should fail (I did not test it, but it looks very much like it)

Comment: @Vityata - I've already tested this formula, why don't you try it yourself.

Comment: @Mrig - it fails in the scenarios I have mentioned. Can you provide a screenshot of them, with a working formula? Put the range somewhere in the middle and the formula cell somewhere unrelated. Or use the cells above I have mentioned.

Comment: @Vityata - You can see screen shots in answer.

Comment: @Mrig - Thumbs up :)

Comment: @Vityata - Phew!!!. Glad it worked. I am removing those screen shots from answer.

Comment: @Mrig - leave them, they are nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula based on OFFSET

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/2),MOD(ROW(A1)-1,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **VBA Macros**, you can do this way:

```
Sub Transpose1()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range("C1").Value = "ID+Name"

    'Get Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Find last row
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, RowCounter As Long: RowCounter = 2
    Dim DestCol As Long
    DestCol = 3

    With ws
        'loop through all rows
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            'set value in row=1,col=3, with value from row=i,col=1
            .Cells(RowCounter, DestCol) = ws.Cells(i, 1)
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1

            'set value in row=2,col=3, with value from row=i,col=2
            .Cells(RowCounter, DestCol) = ws.Cells(i, 2)
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Assuming that you have 2 columns **ID**, **Description** on **Sheet1** on sheet's columns **A** and **B** respectively. This macro will output the desired format in **C** column. Please review comments in code for better understanding.

Comment: I have been using the code and it works perfect! Thank you very much for helping me out with this!